# Google Play Service Activity recognition start and stops itself constantly

Tags: android, google-play-services, activity-recognition

I need to call the Google activity recognition service through a service (not activity) and run it in the background, of course when the user starts the app, which has an activity (But the service does not called directly from activity).

Therefore I have created a service class (ActivitySensor) and another class (ActivityRecognitionScan).
When I install the app on my Galaxy Nexus S device, the service starts calling onCreate and onDestroy automatically. Even without doing anything in the GUI 
It is very strange behaviour. Does anybody has the same experience or solution for it?

I mean I get something as follows in the debug console:
Activity-Logging --- onCreate
Activity-Logging --- onDestroy
Activity-Logging --- onCreate
Activity-Logging --- onDestroy
Activity-Logging --- onCreate
Activity-Logging --- onDestroy
...

Here are my two classes:

```
    public class ActivitySensor extends IntentService {

        private ActivityRecognitionScan myascan;
        private Intent inIntent;
        private static long ACTIVITY_LOG_INTERVAL = 30000L;
        private static JsonEncodeDecode jsonencoder = new JsonEncodeDecode(); 
        public ActivitySensor() {
            super("ActivitySensor");
        }   

        @Override
        public void onCreate(){
            super.onCreate();
            Log.d("Activity-Logging", "--- onCreate");
            try {
                myascan = new ActivityRecognitionScan(getApplicationContext());
                myascan.startActivityRecognitionScan();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("[Activity-Logging]","----------Error:"+e.getLocalizedMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   
        }

        @Override
        public void readSensor() {   
    //      Log.e("Activity-Logging", "ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult: "+String.valueOf(ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(inIntent)));
            if (ActivityRecognitionResult.hasResult(inIntent)) {
                ActivityRecognitionResult result = ActivityRecognitionResult.extractResult(inIntent);
                DetectedActivity activity = result.getMostProbableActivity();
                final int type = activity.getType();
                String strType = new String();
                switch(type){
                  case DetectedActivity.IN_VEHICLE:
                      strType = "invehicle";
                      break;
                  case DetectedActivity.ON_BICYCLE:
                      strType ="onbicycle";
                      break;
                  case DetectedActivity.ON_FOOT:
                      strType = "onfoot";
                      break;
                  case DetectedActivity.STILL:
                      strType = "still";
                      break;
                  case DetectedActivity.TILTING:
                      strType ="tilting";
                      break;
                  case DetectedActivity.UNKNOWN:
                      strType ="unknown";
                      break;
                }
                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                Editor edt = prefs.edit();
                String previousActv = prefs.getString("PREVIOUS_ACTIVIY","");
                long previousDate = prefs.getLong("PREVIOUS_DATE", 0);
                if (previousActv.length()==0){ // nothing was in the string and it is the first time just initialize
                    previousActv = strType;
                    previousDate = new Date().getTime();
    //              Log.e("-----FIRST TIME: type:", previousActv+" date:"+String.valueOf(previousDate));
                    edt.putString("PREVIOUS_ACTIVIY", strType);
                    edt.putLong("PREVIOUS_DATE", previousDate);
                    edt.commit();
                }else {
                    if (!strType.equalsIgnoreCase(previousActv)){
                        Date readablePrevDate = new Date(previousDate);
                        Date nowDate = new Date();
                        String jsonstr = jsonencoder.EncodeActivity("Activity", readablePrevDate, nowDate, strType, activity.getConfidence());
    //                  Log.e("[Activity-Logging] ----->",jsonstr);
                        edt.putString("PREVIOUS_ACTIVIY", strType);
                        edt.putLong("PREVIOUS_DATE", nowDate.getTime());
                        edt.commit();
                        DataAcquisitor.dataBuff.add(jsonstr);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            Log.d("Activity-Logging", "--- onHandleIntent"+ "---"+intent.getAction());
            intent.putExtra("LOG_INTERVAL",ACTIVITY_LOG_INTERVAL );
            intent.putExtra("STOP",false);
            inIntent = intent;
            readSensor();
        }   

        @Override
        public void onDestroy(){
            Log.d("Activity-Logging", "--- onDestroy");
            myascan.stopActivityRecognitionScan();
            myascan=null;
            //super.onDestroy();
        }
}
```

This is the class that calls the Google Activity Recognition Service:

```
ActivityRecognitionScan implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private Context ctx;
    private static final String TAG = "ActivityRecognition";
    private static ActivityRecognitionClient actrecClient;
    private static PendingIntent callbackIntent;
    private long ACTIVITY_LOG_INTERVAL=30000;
    public ActivityRecognitionScan(Context context) {
        ctx=context;
    }

    public void startActivityRecognitionScan(){
        int resp = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(ctx);
        if(resp == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
            actrecClient = new ActivityRecognitionClient(ctx, this, this);
            if (!actrecClient.isConnected()){
                actrecClient.connect();
            } else{
                Log.e("ActivityRecognitionScan"," ---Activity recognition client is already connected");
            }
        }else{
                Log.e("[Activity-Logging]", "Google Play Service hasn't installed");
        }

    }

    public void stopActivityRecognitionScan(){
        try{
            if (actrecClient.isConnected() || actrecClient.isConnecting() ){
                actrecClient.removeActivityUpdates(callbackIntent);
                actrecClient.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.e("[ActivityRecognitionScan]", "Connection Failed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        try{
            Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, ActivitySensor.class); 
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras(); 
            callbackIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ctx, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            long interval = 5000;
            if ( null!= bundle && bundle.containsKey("LOG_INTERVAL") ){
                interval = bundle.getLong("LOG_INTERVAL");
            }
            actrecClient.requestActivityUpdates(interval, callbackIntent);  
            actrecClient.disconnect();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            Log.e("[Activity-Logging]","Error in requesting Activity update "+ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        callbackIntent.cancel();
        actrecClient = null;
        Log.e("[ActivityRecognitionScan]","---onDisconnected");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`IntentService` automatically stops itself on completion of `onHandleIntent` as per [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/IntentService.java) (see `ServiceHandler.handleMessage()`) as per [the description of an IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html):

> Clients send requests through startService(Intent) calls; the service is started as needed, handles each Intent in turn using a worker thread, and stops itself when it runs out of work.

Use a `Service` if you want it to run continuously in the background.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but to the best of my knowledge in order to update an activity request I need to pass an intent, the service is not possible. I mean here:  `actrecClient.requestActivityUpdates(interval, callbackIntent);` If there is solution that I can make it run without the callbackIntent I'll immediately switch to the service.

Comment: You don't need to use an `IntentService` to get access to the incoming `Intent` - [Service.onStartCommand](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)) gives you access to the same `Intent` that you would get in `onHandleIntent`.

Comment: I have used `Service` class and again the weird behavior remain. I stop the service is starts itself automatically. So it was not the problem of IntentService or Service, it is somewhere else, which I can't recognize yet.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues with your code that is causing the problem you are experiencing.

1. When activity is detected, the pending intent that is called calls (and creates, since it is an IntentService) ActivitySensor.  The onCreate will connect another ActivityRecognitionClient, which is unnecessary.  This causes another activity to be detected which causes your logging loop.
2. You should separate the creation of the ActivityRecognitionClient from the handling of the detected activity.  You don't need to keep recreating it as subsequent detections will use the same PendingIntent.  This will prevent the logging loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you have an example which resolve this inside the code ? I didn't understand point one, which I think is the origin of this problem. Also can you explain why do I need to separate them in your point 2 ?